# How to get last inserted records

Tags: c#, .net, file, c#-4.0, logging

I have a `.txt` log file which have some records which are appended to the file on minute basis. The number of records that are appended in an minute is dynamic. ie, if in a minute, it appends 2 records, then in the next minute, 5 records may get added. The content of file looks like below

```
"2015-Dec-19 02:00:00 AM", "Apple"
"2015-Dec-19 02:00:00 AM", "Orange"
"2015-Dec-19 02:01:00 AM", "Carrot"
"2015-Dec-19 02:01:00 AM", "Onion"
"2015-Dec-19 02:01:00 AM", "Beans"
"2015-Dec-19 02:01:00 AM", "Banana"
"2015-Dec-19 02:01:00 AM", "Apple"
```

Going forward, the size of the file will become large and it would be difficult to filter the records. Is there any way in `C#` that I can find out from the property of file, how many records are added last time without opening the file? ie, in the above example, 5 records are added at `2015-Dec-19 02:01:00 AM`. So I need to get the count as 5.
I know only how to get the file properties with the below code, but not sure how to fill my requirement from the code.

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("C:\Demo.txt");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Text is text, and it is stored as binary data. The OS nor the framework have any notion of records, or lines, or dates in your file. It only knows when the file was created, and when it was last modified.

If you want to assign a meaning to certain words in a file, you'll have to read the file's contents and parse it to get that meaning back out of the file. The OS or framework will not help you here.

It looks like you actually want a database.

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, if you need to work with large files, and query for dates, my suggestion is to switch to SQLite (very well supported on c #).

However you could keep track of the size of your file with FileInfo and soon reopened compare with the new length (this will only works with fixed-length records.)

New records added = (currentLenght - lastLenght) / recordSize

But no way to directly query dates in a binary file